# How to reorder flex items from two separate parent elements at a specific screen width using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a grid with two columns, and in the columns there are divs with different height and width. It is necessary to know that when we click on a div, its content toggles down (show/hide with jquery), so divs can change their heights also. For showing my contents in importance from screen view top to down, the order is in line (row). My problem is the mobile version because when I resize the page, the order will be by columns, and not as in line.

```css
.grid {position:relative;display:flex;flex-flow:row wrap;justify-content:space-between;width:100%;max-width:1200px;margin:0 auto;padding:20px;background:grey}
.column {position:relative;display:flex;flex-flow:row wrap;align-content:start;width:49.5%;background:white}
.column1 {justify-content:right;}
.column2 {justify-content:left;}
.item {width:97.5%;max-width:720px;max-height:720px;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:30px}
.item1 {width:80%;height:100px;background:red}
.item2 {width:50%;height:190px;background:blue}
.item3 {width:40%;height:80px;background:green}
.item4 {width:100%;height:50px;background:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="grid">
  <div class="column column1">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column2">
    <div class="item item2">2</div>
    <div class="item item4">4</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image: image example what I am looking for]

I found a lot of questions/answers about grid and divs order but all of them are in the same columns or rows. I am still looking for a CSS or JS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an odd request that cannot be handled with modern CSS.

I created a function that swaps the elements by inserting a marker at the desired location of object 1. There are more details on this function located in the comments of the JS.

I then created a [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) by calling the [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method on the `window` object.

> A `MediaQueryList` object stores information on a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) applied to a document, with support for both immediate and event-driven matching against the state of the document. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList)

So with this said, I used an event-driven listener that is invoked by a conditional statement whenever the screen is below or equal to `1000px`.

```js
function swapElements(obj1, obj2) {
  // create marker element and insert it where object 1 is
  var mkr = document.createElement("div");
  obj1.parentNode.insertBefore(mkr, obj1);

  // move object 1 to right before object 2
  obj2.parentNode.insertBefore(obj1, obj2);

  // move object 2 to right before where object 1 used to be
  mkr.parentNode.insertBefore(obj2, mkr);

  // remove temporary marker node
  mkr.parentNode.removeChild(mkr);
}

// create function with if - else statement
function setMediaQuery(x) {
  if (x.matches) {
    swapElements(document.querySelector(".item3"), document.querySelector(".item2"));
  }
}

// create a MediaQueryListObject
const mediaQueryMax = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1000px)");
const mediaQueryMin = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)");

// call the match function at run time
setMediaQuery(mediaQueryMax);

// add the match function as a listener for state changes
mediaQueryMax.addListener(setMediaQuery)
mediaQueryMin.addListener(setMediaQuery)
```

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: grey
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: start;
  width: 49.5%;
  background: white
}

.column1 {
  justify-content: right;
}

.column2 {
  justify-content: left;
}

.item {
  width: 97.5%;
  max-width: 720px;
  max-height: 720px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px
}

.item1 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red
}

.item2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 190px;
  background: blue
}

.item3 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80px;
  background: green
}

.item4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column1,
  .column2 {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .grid,
  .column {
    row-gap: 1em;
  }
  .grid {
    background: transparent;
    border: solid 18px grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <div class="column column1">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column2">
    <div class="item item2">2</div>
    <div class="item item4">4</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Super, thanks a lot, it works ! Maybe can you tell me also what to do that elements change with resizing page, and without refreshing the page ?

Comment: @IgorLaszlo can you rephrase?

Comment: sorry for my English... Those above changes are shown only after refresh (reload) the page. Is it possible to change the orders without reloading the page ? With resizing the page only by mouse for example. If possible, how can I do it ?

Comment: @IgorLaszlo All set, see edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media only screen` to set divs in one column from or to a certain width and use `grid` but then you will have rows same height and If you don't want this you can use js to replace childs. like this.

script.js

```js
let item1 = document.querySelector(".item1");
let item2 = document.querySelector(".item2");
let item3 = document.querySelector(".item3");
let item4 = document.querySelector(".item4");

let doneOnce = false;
let prevWidth = false;
let widthChanged = false;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (width <= 600) {
        item3.replaceWith(item2);
        item4.parentElement.insertBefore(item3, item4);
    }
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
    height = document.body.clientHeight;
    if (
        (width <= 600 && prevWidth > 600 && prevWidth) ||
        (width > 600 && prevWidth <= 600 && prevWidth)
    ) {
        doneOnce = false;
        widthChanged = true;
    }
   
    if (width <= 600 && !doneOnce && widthChanged) {
        item3.replaceWith(item2);
        item4.parentElement.insertBefore(item3, item4);
        doneOnce = true;
    } else if (width > 600 && !doneOnce && widthChanged) {
        item2.replaceWith(item3);
        item4.parentElement.insertBefore(item2, item4);
        doneOnce = true;
    }
    prevWidth = width;
});
```

style.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: grey;
}
.column {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: start;
    width: 49.5%;
    background: white;
}
.column1 {
    justify-content: right;
}
.column2 {
    justify-content: left;
}
.item {
    width: 97.5%;
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 720px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.item1 {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.item2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 190px;
    background: blue;
}
.item3 {
    width: 40%;
    height: 80px;
    background: green;
}
.item4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .grid {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .grid > div {
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <main class="grid">
        <div class="column column1">
            <div class="item item1">1</div>
            <div class="item item3">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column column2">
            <div class="item item2">2</div>
            <div class="item item4">4</div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Take a look at the screenshots. The mobile version should be 1, 2, 3, 4. In your code it is 1, 3, 2, 4

Comment: oh sorry. I will fix this

Comment: Ah, so I just can replace the items, but the two columns remain displayed. I was fixing on the problem that I can not take the items out of the columns, so I was blocked. Now I do not have time to try it, I will come back tomorrow if it works for me or not. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Kameron's answer but in the meantime I found a more simple way... First the items of the column 2. must be appended to the column 1., then I put the ex column 2. items between the column 1. items. At the end I do not display the empty column 2.

```
if($(window).width() <= 800){
    // 1st step
    $('.item2').appendTo('.column1')
    $('.item4').appendTo('.column1')
    // 2nd step
    $('.item1 + .item3').before($('.item2'));
    $('.item3 + .item5').before($('.item4'));
    // 3rd step
    $('.column2').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: My version is pure JS. No jQuery was used. Also, in your solution, it looks like once you resize the screen back up over `800px` the elements do not assume their original position. I made a few changes to my answer and handled the request you asked for.

Comment: @Kameron so you can see, I do not know so much jquery, and pure javascripts even less... I thought that it is jquery, just I never saw those codes :)
Yes, it is true also, I upvoted instead of accepting, now I do it.
I did not look at your edit yet, I do now... Thanks again for all !